# SyntaxError: invalid syntax using dash

Tags: python

I tried to import a library which is named `monitoring-network-logs`, but I got a syntxError which indicate that the `-` who makes the problem:

```
from monitoring-network-logs import *
               ^
```

shouldn't I use the dash, if the dash who make the problem, is the another alternative to force use it?

Comment: Use underscores instead? Or shorten it to `mnlogs`.

Comment: @TrebledJ we used to use dash to name files in our  env, so I need to use dash!!

Comment: Then your env is unsuitable for Python development.